# How to avoid the system command execution successful message?

Tags: perl

I am executing the following Perl command:

```
system ("cvs ci a.txt");
```

and it is displaying the CVS message. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going to be running system commands like this in a unix environment, the obvious thing works.

```
system("cvs ci a.txt > /dev/null");
```

You might want to consider something like IPC::Run3, too, to allow you to gather the output from stdout and stderr to use as you see fit.